# Failed assertion: line 137 pos 15: 'assetName != null': is not true. in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show image from local database, with grid view. but it not showing up, there is some debug over here but i cant understand what is the problem.

[image]

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart': Failed assertion: line 137 pos 15: 'assetName != null': is not true.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart': Failed assertion: line 137 pos 15: 'assetName != null': is not true.
```

, it seems like something wrong with image url asset, i try to find in other stack forum but cant find solution. can somebody help me me.

this is my main code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plantgo_alpha/constans/color_constans.dart';
import 'package:plantgo_alpha/models/data.dart';

class Forum extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var body = Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: Data.tanaman.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Card(
                  color: Color(Data.tanaman[index]
                      .color), //ganti sama color di data nanti!!!
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    height: 50,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: Data.tanaman[index].id,
                              child: FadeInImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(Data.tanaman[index].image),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                placeholder:
                                    AssetImage('assets/images/loading.gif'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text(
                            Data.tanaman[index].title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: kBlackColor,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my data

```
import "package:plantgo_alpha/models/class.dart";

class Data {
  static List<Tanaman> tanaman = [
    Tanaman(
        id: '1',
        title: 'Sawi Hidroponik',
        image: 'assets/images/sawi0.jpg',
        steps: [
          'Siapkan alat dan Bahan : 1.Rockwoll, 2.Sprayer/Penyemprot Air, 3.Pinset, 4.Benih Sawi',
          'Siapkan media tanam, potong rockwool setebal 2,5 cm. Iris memanjang sedalam kurang lebih 1 cm menjadi 3 bagian dan iris melintang menjadi 6 bagian sedalam 1 cm. Lihat gambar di bawah ini untuk detailnya.',
          'Masukkan benih ke dalam lubang dengan posisi kecambah di bawah (1 lubang diisi 1 benih)'
              'tes enter',
          'Setelah semua lubang terisi, basahi rockwool menggunakan sprayer/semprotan dengan kekuatan air yang lembut. Taruh semaian di tempat terbuka yang cukup sinar matahari.',
          'Pada tahap ini adalah tahap perawatan semai, jaga rockwool agar tetap lembab (tidak terlalu basah dan tidak terlalu kering)',
          'Setelah sawi berdaun 3 atau lebih, sudah waktunya untuk dipindah ke sistem hidroponik dan diberi nutrisi hidroponik. Umur sawi sekitar 7-10 hari setelah semai.',
          'Step ini adalah tahap pindah tanam. Pisahkan/potong rockwool berdasarkan irisan yang dibuat pada step awal. Apabila susah untuk memisahkan rockwool, maka bisa menggunakan cutter untuk memotong rockwool sampe terpisah. Taruh potongan rockwool ke dalam netpot yang sudah dikasih flanel (sumbu)',
          'Letakkan netpot ke dalam sistem hidroponik, pada tahap ini nutrisi yang diberikan kepekatannya 600 ppm. Kepekatan nutrisi dinaikkan setelah masuk 5 hari setelah pindah tanam menjadi 800 ppm. Setelah memasuki 10 hari setelah tanam, naikkan kepekatan nutrisi menjadi 1200 ppm. Jaga ppm nutrisi selalu stabil di angka tersebut sampai panen.',
          'Masa Panen Sayur Sawi Hidroponik adalah sekitar 30-40 hari dengan cara dicabut beserta akarnya.'
        ],
        tools: ['Rockwoll', 'Sprayer/penyemprot air', 'pinset', 'Benih Sawi'],
        color: 0xFFD3EB91),
    Tanaman(
        id: '2',
        title: 'Bayam Hidroponik',
        image: 'assets/images/sawi1.jpg',
        steps: [
          'Siapkan alat dan Bahan : 1.Rockwoll, 2.Sprayer/Penyemprot Air, 3.Pinset, 4.Benih Sawi',
          'Siapkan media tanam, potong rockwool setebal 2,5 cm. Iris memanjang sedalam kurang lebih 1 cm menjadi 3 bagian dan iris melintang menjadi 6 bagian sedalam 1 cm. Lihat gambar di bawah ini untuk detailnya.',
          'Masukkan benih ke dalam lubang dengan posisi kecambah di bawah (1 lubang diisi 1 benih)'
              'tes enter',
          'Setelah semua lubang terisi, basahi rockwool menggunakan sprayer/semprotan dengan kekuatan air yang lembut. Taruh semaian di tempat terbuka yang cukup sinar matahari.',
          'Pada tahap ini adalah tahap perawatan semai, jaga rockwool agar tetap lembab (tidak terlalu basah dan tidak terlalu kering)',
          'Setelah sawi berdaun 3 atau lebih, sudah waktunya untuk dipindah ke sistem hidroponik dan diberi nutrisi hidroponik. Umur sawi sekitar 7-10 hari setelah semai.',
          'Step ini adalah tahap pindah tanam. Pisahkan/potong rockwool berdasarkan irisan yang dibuat pada step awal. Apabila susah untuk memisahkan rockwool, maka bisa menggunakan cutter untuk memotong rockwool sampe terpisah. Taruh potongan rockwool ke dalam netpot yang sudah dikasih flanel (sumbu)',
          'Letakkan netpot ke dalam sistem hidroponik, pada tahap ini nutrisi yang diberikan kepekatannya 600 ppm. Kepekatan nutrisi dinaikkan setelah masuk 5 hari setelah pindah tanam menjadi 800 ppm. Setelah memasuki 10 hari setelah tanam, naikkan kepekatan nutrisi menjadi 1200 ppm. Jaga ppm nutrisi selalu stabil di angka tersebut sampai panen.',
          'Masa Panen Sayur Sawi Hidroponik adalah sekitar 30-40 hari dengan cara dicabut beserta akarnya.'
        ],
        tools: ['Rockwoll', 'Sprayer/penyemprot air', 'pinset', 'Benih Sawi'],
        color: 0xFFD3EB91),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure an asset like this `Data.tanaman[index].image` really exists? Print the value and make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed, i already find the answer by change the `NetworkImage` to `AssetImage` in my code, then re run the debugging.